# Makefile - use variable in git command

Tags: makefile

in `Makefile` I want to clone repository with specific tag. Firstly, I specific `LATEST_TAG` variable and then I want to use it in second command. My code looks like:

```
$(M1P):
  ifndef M1P_COMMIT
    LATEST_TAG=$(shell git ls-remote --tags --sort=-v:refname git@github.NAME.com:ORG/REPOSITORY.git | awk '{print $2}' | grep -o 'v.*' | head -1)
    git clone --branch $(LATEST_TAG) git@github.NAME.com:ORG/REPOSITORY.git
```

When code is executed, text: `LATEST_TAG=8.1.2` is displayed in console and when second command is executed, I'm getting `git clone --branch`, so it looks like my variable `LATEST_TAG` is not called in command with clone. How can I use this variable?

Comment: `LATEST_TAG` is assigned only in that shell (remember, a separate shell is started for each make command).  It's not assigning a Make variable.  You probably want `LATEST_TAG=…` before the rule, and without a tab indent.

Comment: Or, perhaps you want to create a shell variable: `LATEST_TAG=$$(git …); git clone --branch $$LATEST_TAG …`?  Remember to use ```\``` if splitting across two lines.

Comment: @TobySpeight so second option looks definitely better, but I'm not sure if correct tag is cloned, because I'm getting information in console: git clone $$LATEST_TAG. My code looks like that at this moment:

```
$(M1P):
  ifndef M1P_COMMIT
    LATEST_TAG=$$(git ls-remote --tags --sort=-v:refname git@github.NAME.com:ORG/REPO.git | awk '{print $2}' | grep -o 'v.*' | head -1);\
    git clone --branch $$LATEST_TAG git@github.NAME.com:ORG/REPOgit;\
    cd $(M1P); git branch
```

Comment: @TobySpeight I was able to deal with that problem and yeah, I'm on proper tag